# Proving a succession with its limit is compact on the usual topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A=\{\ell\}\cup\{a_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ where $a_n\to\ell$. Prove $A$ is compact in $(\Bbb R, \tau_e)$.

I tried the following:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an open cover for $A$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. Now, we need to find a finite subcover.

Since $a_n\to\ell$, then $a_k\in (\ell-\varepsilon,\ell+\varepsilon)=U_\varepsilon$ where $k\geq N_\varepsilon$. So now, if $U_\varepsilon\subseteq\mathcal{C}$ then we are done, since there are finite elements outside of $U_\varepsilon$, so we can take a finite open sets that cover each one on them and thus, we get a finite subcover. The problem though, is that I'm stuck at proving $U_\varepsilon\subseteq\mathcal{C}$. The tricky part is when an element of $U_\varepsilon$ is not an element of $A$. If the element is also an element of $A$, since $A$ is covered, then clearly the element is also in $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the collection $\mathcal{C}$ is an open cover for $A$ and $\ell \in A$, there must be some open set $U_0 \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $\ell \in U_0$. Since $U_0$ is open and $\ell \in U_0$, there is $\varepsilon>0$ so that $$(\ell-\varepsilon,\ell+\varepsilon) \subseteq U_0.$$
Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\ell$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that
$$|a_n-\ell|< \varepsilon \text{ whenever } n \geq N.$$
Now there are at most finitely many ($N-1$ or $N$ depending if you include $0\in \mathbb{N}$) elements in $A$ that are not in $U_0$ but since $\mathcal{C}$ is a cover this just means we choose a set from $\mathcal{C}$ for each one of these finitely many terms at the start of the sequence $\{a_n\}$.

---

Hope this helped but not too much.